# Browser cannot get reponse from fuseki if a long running query is executed

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, reverse-proxy, fuseki

Recently I have configured a reverse proxy(apache2 in ubuntu 16) for fuseki2 as a web application using tomcat7. However, there is a problem still confusing me that I can only get results if I execute some simple queries which don't need a long processing time (less than 10mins in chrome exactly) from the backend. I will otherwise get a print of "unable to get a response from endpoint". The timeout is strictly 10mins. I have increased the timeout for fuseki2 as well as the reverse proxy, but this doesn't work for me.

I have traced the error.log in apache2 and catalina.out in tomcat and found no error. Besides, Tomcat is keep runing when "no response" error appears in Chrome.

Anyone has any idea about this? Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: see also http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201803.mbox/%3C57A63F47-221B-45C0-A08D-920D44017400@apache.org%3E